# I can't create a UV map for this object and I don't know why (sphere unwrap)

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I have a horse model I'm working on. So far, so good.

Now I'm trying to add eyes with an iris texture. I added two spheres, assigned a material and a texture, but the UV Map is too small and needs to be resized (my horse now has insect eyes. Every face of the sphere has its own texture.)

When I try to apply/resize my UV Map (in Edit mode), here is what I get:

[image: No UV map]

The sphere has a Material & texture, so it *should* work:
[image]

So, what am I doing wrong? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

The faces of your sphere are overlapping in the *UV Editor* because you must have unwrapped with the *Unwrap* option (first one) without any seam on your mesh. The result is that each face displays the pupil. You should mark a seam on one of your sphere longitudes (select the edge and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Mark Seam*), then select all and unwrap again (with the first option called *Unwrap*). This time it will take the seam into account. You can bring some corrections like scaling up and down the UV in the *UV Editor* and align it to the pupil.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I "mark a seam on one of your sphere longitudes"? Must I select every vertices by hand all the way around? Because simply using Ctrl-E alone does not appear to do the trick (in Edit Mode.)

Comment: in 2.79, alt left click should work to select an edge loop

Comment: Thx. I must be missing something though. I'm still not getting a UV Map. I select the seam (alt+LMB), Mark Seam, Unwrap, Select All (as in your photo), and get the same "too many faces selected" white box (in UV Edit mode.) If I don't Select All, I get the texture, but still no UV Map. :(

Comment: Once you've marked the seam, select all then unwrap with the first option selected (Unwrap). I don't know this "too many faces selected" error...

Comment: Ah! Unwrap AFTER selecting All! That was my mistake. The "error" I described is when you select too many faces in "UV Edit" mode, it doesn't know what to map, so you get the white box seen in my first photo. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unwrapping it with Sphere Projection? (One of the Unwrap options)

How about using a Texture Coordinate with Mapping node to manually arrange it? (Texture Coordinate (UV Data) plugged into Mapping plugged into Image Texture plugged into Shader—adjusting the Mapping parameters to fit).

John